# Render a main menu into a fixed navbar when scrolling on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using **bootstrap** latest version.

I create a **main menu** like this:
[image]

This is the **code** for in my html view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
              <p>header Menu 1</p>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>
              <p>header Menu 2</p>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
              <p>header Menu 3</p>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
              <p>header Menu 4</p>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-nav">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
              <p>header Menu 5</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like, **when user scrolling**, change this menu into a fixed to top navbar like this ([check the link to have a better idea](http://www.bootply.com/render/JH8sMk1aIW#), scroll to see the animation):
[image]

this is the code for the nav fixed to top:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-thumbnail-preview">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="dropdown-thumbnail-preview">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            {# Suivis Fluides #}
            <li class="dropdown thumb-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Header Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">
                            sub menu 1
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            sub menu 2
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {# Suivis Contrats #}
            <li class="dropdown thumb-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Header Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">
                            sub menu 1
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            sub menu 2
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {# Gestion Patrimoines #}
            <li class="dropdown thumb-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Header Menu 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">
                            sub menu 1
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            sub menu 2
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {# Gestion Equipements Technique #}
            <li class="dropdown thumb-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Header Menu 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                            sub menu 1
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            sub menu 2
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            {# User #}
            <li class="dropdown thumb-dropdown navbar-right">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Header 5 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                            sub menu 1
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            sub menu 2
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dark-Wallpaper-HQ-Photos-Desktop.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**The purpose of this question is to render my main menu into a navbar fixed to top when user is scrolling.**

Anybody knows what is the best solution and to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all , I found a solution for my project, following the specification of my clients.

First, I add an id to the button nav, named firstMainMenu. Then, I add an id for the navbar named secondMainMenu. I add an hidden class for the navbar and make the script.

This is the script for:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>222) {
            $('#secondMainMenu').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn();
            $('#firstMainMenu').addClass('hidden').fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
            $('#secondMainMenu').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#firstMainMenu').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
```

This is the code who works for me. But the three answer are right too. Tahnk you to all of you for your suggestions. You are the best.

Don't hesitate if you have suggestions or edits for this script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [`Prinzhorn/skrollr`](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [`imakewebthings/waypoints`](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) to define, when (talking about scroll position) to add/remove a class which makes the `navbar` sticky.

Comment: I found a solution who works for my project and my client validate it. I keep a look on the bundle/package you show, it seems to be interesting for future feartures. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below if you have an option of including `jquery`

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the 
      //nav bar to stick.  
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) //Change this value 280 as per your need
    {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank you, I post my answer. The script I have poste works well for me and my client. But thanks to you too I made it. Best regards...

Answer (score 1):

Considering the structure of each navigation is different, I would suggest **hiding/showing** each element with a css class of `hidden`. Then it's just a matter of **adding/removing** that class when the first nav is scrolled equal to or passed the top of the viewport.

The jQuery would look something like this:

```
//Fired when the page is scrolling
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var window = $(this);
    //Create a reference to both navigations
    var buttonNav = $('#buttonNav');
    var fixedNav = $('#fixedNav');

    if(window.scrollTop() >= buttonNav.offset().top) {
        //Hide the buttonNav and Show the fixed nav
        buttonNav.addClass('hidden');
        fixedNav.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        //The opposite
        fixedNav.addClass('hidden');
        buttonNav.removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to add id's to each nav in order to reference them with jQuery and the `hidden` class just needs the css property `display: none;` in it. Hope this helps :)